# Change php.ini location

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, php, homebrew

Is it possible to change the location of `php.ini` to be used by Apache? When I did `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`, the result is:

> Path => /usr/local/etc
>
> Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php.ini

But the result of `phpinfo()` is

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path : /etc

I can copy over `php.ini` from `/usr/local/etc/` to `/etc/`, but is it possible to change the php.ini folder?

I installed PHP using homebrew and I am using OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: If it's installed as a module, use PHPIniDir.

Comment: @Zendy how did you solved this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHP uses different `.ini` files when running via command line vs running as a web server module. When you grep the results of `php -i` your getting the command line ini. It's good practice to have separate ini's for the two environments.

If you must change the directory PHP looks for the `php.ini` file, you can use the `PHPIniDir` in your web server conf file.

If you wish to just add additional directories to be scanned, you can set the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: ok, and where do i add that `PHPIniDir` or `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`? Do i just add it to `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Oh, and if you don't mind me asking, why is it good practice to have separate ini's for two different environments?

Comment: `PHPIniDir` goes in `httpd.conf`. `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` is an environment variable and needs to be exported via the user that runs apache. Multiple configs is common simply because the environments are different enough to warrant their own settings (one is initiated by the user, the other by anonymous web requests).

Comment: My httpd.conf file is empty and when I add PHPIniDir="path to folder of server" then apache crashes when I restart it. (coming from http://serverfault.com/questions/469398/cant-load-my-php-ini-on-localhost#comment517606_469398)

Comment: thanks `export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php.d/` solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

To Change php.ini file path we have to  declare PHPINIDir in the apache configuration file 'httpd.conf'  syntax for that is :

```
PHPINIDir "path_to_ini_file";
```

Comment: There should be no semicolon at the end, just simply `PHPINIDir "/etc/php.ini"`, and then don't forget to restart your apache (i.e., `sudo apachectl restart`)