# How to set default php.ini to be used, OSX Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache

I set up a new environment using OSX Yosemite.

I'm using the built-in PHP.

I'd like to change some config in php.ini such as date.timezone but none of the modifications are working despite restarting the apache server (sudo apachectl restart).

phpinfo() is giving a different path than php --ini command.

phpinfo():

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/php5/lib
>
> Loaded Configuration File /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

Via commands :

> which php
>
> /usr/bin/php
>
> php --ini
>
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

So I guess I have to tell somewhere where I should set the default php.ini to be used.

Any ideas, hints?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

move the configuration file to the right spot and update the timezone.

```
$ sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Open the config file /etc/php.ini, find the line that sets your timezone and update it correspondingly.

```
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

Do not forget to remove the ; at the beginning.
Restart the Apache server to have PHP load the new .ini file.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Just to add, if someone is wondering where to find the 'right' php.ini (and above one is not working), see http://serverfault.com/a/466625/351759.

Comment: Worked for me on El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

> SAPI module specific location (PHPIniDir directive in Apache 2, -c command line option in CGI and CLI, php_ini parameter in NSAPI, PHP_INI_PATH environment variable in THTTPD)

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Try changing `PHPIniDir` in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't really help. I still can't figure it out where i can change it.

I didn't find any PHPIniDir or Anything similar in my httpd.conf

Comment: Have you tried to add it to `httpd.conf`?

Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10386320/1479812

Comment: Almost but i don't know why it takes /private/etc/php.ini and not /etc/php.ini. I set it like that PHPINIDir "/etc/php.ini"

Answer (score 1):

On mac sierra with php7.1, edit /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini won't work, you can edit like this:

1)  `cp /etc/php.ini.default php.ini`
2) edit php.ini to add
     `date.timezone = Europe/Berlin`

then restart your apache,

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If you're on mac and you have the file /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini then edit timezone there and it will effect php-cgi (web-browser)

Long answer:
n mac system for few settings like timezone php.ini file (showing loaded in phpinfo) don't work. Because sometimes we unknowingly install php packaged by Liip. That's why apache picks up few settings from liip-developer.ini config file which is usually located at /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini