# Strange PHP .ini inclusion in CLI vs Built-in server

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug

My current config: 
- MacOS Mojave
- PHP 7.3.5 installed via Homebrew
- XDebug 2.7.2 installed via PECL
- get_loaded_extensions() in both CLI and built-in server is enabled

While trying to configure XDebug on Mac I came across a strange problem.
When calling

```
$ php --ini
```

I get

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```

whereas calling

```
print php_ini_scanned_files();
```

in the script executed via built-in PHP server yields

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

Web server does not include my `xdebug` config, therefore there is no way to set `xdebug.remote_enable=1` option properly.

What is even "better" is that editing `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini` to cause parsing errors gives no warnings whatsoever.

I'm puzzled. Does anyone has any idea what's the reason behind this?

Comment: I don’t know anything on this but have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/27861720/735926?