# Php Can't find Stomp class

Tags: php, stomp

I'm trying to get a queue from activemq using a PHP client. I included in the project a stomp library. Here is my project tree:

```
TestPhp/
├── PhpInfo.php
├── SimpleStompConsumer.php
└── Stomp
    ├── Exception
    |   └── StompException.php
    ├── ExceptionInterface.php
    ├── Frame.php
    ├── Message
    │   ├── Bytes.php
    │   └── Map.php
    ├── Message.php
    └── Stomp.php
```

and here is my code

```
<?php
$path = "/var/www/test/TestPhp/Stomp/Stomp.php";

require_once($path);
$con = new Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");
$con->connect();
$con->subscribe("/queue/test");
$msg = $con->readFrame();


if( $msg != null) {
    echo "Received message with body '$msg->body'\n";
    $con->ack($msg);
} else {
echo "Failed to receive a message\n";
}
$con->disconnect();

?>
```

When I run the php file I get the following error and I don' know what to do. 
     `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Stomp' not found in /var/www/test/TestPhp/SimpleStompConsumer.php on line 5 
PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/test/TestPhp/SimpleStompConsumer.php:0`

I'd appreciate any directives. Thanks.

```
Edit:
```

Library is called Stomp. Here is the 
[github](https://github.com/dejanb/stomp-php) link 
and the [download](https://codeload.github.com/dejanb/stomp-php/zip/master) link

```
Edit:
```

Change `$con = new Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");`
 to `$con = new FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");` $con = new FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");

```
ERROR returned:
```

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FuseSource\Stomp\Exception\StompException' not found in /var/www/test/TestPhp/Stomp/Stomp.php on line 174
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/test/TestPhp/SimpleStompConsumer.php:0
PHP   2. FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp->connect() /var/www/test/TestPhp/SimpleStompConsumer.php:6
PHP   3. FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp->_makeConnection() /var/www/test/TestPhp/Stomp/Stomp.php:195`

Comment: Is the class actually called `Stomp`? Can you link to the library you're using?

Comment: Could it be that I have the wrong library? I tried to download from [FuseSource](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html) but the link is kinda dead.

Comment: What do you have on lines 174 and 195 in Stomp.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stomp library is a composer package, so you need composer class loader or any other PSR-0 compatible, see this https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md.

Example PSR-0 class loader from PHP-Fig: https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634

```
require_once 'path_to_spl_class_loader.php';
$loader = new SplClassLoader('FuseSource\Stomp', __DIR__.'/Stomp');
$loader->register();
new FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp();
```

Besides it's namespaced class, add this line to you file:

```
use FuseSource\Stomp\Stop;
new Stomp();
```

Or use

```
new FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$con = new FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");
```

(namespace).

Edit: One "Stomp" was missing.

Comment: Maybe try again with missing 'Stomp'

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that `stomp.so` was not registered in my PHP engine in Apache. I had used `pear` to install stomp which correctly registered it in my command line PHP engine.

The PHP engine in my Apache is using a `/etc/php.ini` file separate from `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini` used by the PHP engine running on my local command line. As far as I can tell, this is the recommended configuration (see [Change php.ini location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386188/change-php-ini-location))

To remedy I needed to add `extension="stomp.so"` to the `/etc/php.ini` file used by my Apache service and then restart Apache.

My code does not have a `require_once`. I simply invoke `$con = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613', $user, $password);` directly