# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stomp' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, stomp

I've downloaded the library available in: https://github.com/dejanb/stomp-php

and then implemented the following code:

```
<?php

   use FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp;
   (...)
$data=array($data1,$data2, $data3, $data4);
$json = json_encode($data, true);


$user = getenv("ACTIVEMQ_USER"); 
if( !$user ) $user = "admin";

$password = getenv("ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD");
if( !$password ) $password = "password";

$destination  = '/topic/event';
$messages = 10000;
$size = 256;

$DATA = "calls";
$body = $data;
for($i=0; $i< $size; $i++) {
  $body .= $DATA[ $i % 26];
}

try {
  $url = 'tcp://localhost:61613';
  $con = new Stomp($url, $user, $password);

  for($i=0; $i< $messages; $i++) {
    $con->send($destination, $body);
    if( $i%1000 == 0 ) {
      echo "Sent ".$i." messages\n";
    }
  }

  $stomp->send($destination, "SHUTDOWN");

} catch(StompException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stomp' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/skeleton-application/test.php:80

UPDATE: 
I reinstalled using `composer` as suggested at https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php.

I required the autoloader using

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

and added the following imports

```
use Stomp\Client;
use Stomp\StatefulStomp;
use Stomp\Network\Connection;
use Stomp\Transport\Message;
```

Still same error... Do I need to do anything special with my activemq broker or something? I ran it through the console... but still nothing

Comment: Where is test.php and the library ? (I mean project structure)

Comment: What do you mean by *I've downloaded the library*? Have you installed it using composer?

Comment: Unrelated, but as you can see at https://github.com/dejanb/stomp-php#this-project-has-been-deprecated, the project has been deprecated. It is suggested to use https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php Can't find Stomp class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326944/php-cant-find-stomp-class)

Comment: I have the test.php on my project folder and there i have Fuse/stomp/stomp..

Comment: @localheinz I've seen it, done it, did not solve...
The library i did not installed via composer

Comment: Well, if you are using `composer`, you should install the library with `composer`, too. Adjusted my answer below.

Comment: How about importing `Stomp\Stomp`?

Comment: You should read up on http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php.

Comment: @localheinz you mean cloning into the directory? that was what I did originally...

Comment: No. Do you even understand the concept of namespaces?

Comment: @localheinz I used 'use' because it was used in the example... Is that the problem?

Comment: @localheinz yes, I have try with namespace Stomp\Stomp, and several other combinations

Comment: Your code has a range of problems, not importing the appropriate classes with `use` statements is just one of them. You apparently have undefined variables, and apart from that, the code you have written uses the predecessor of `stomp-php/stomp-php`. All of these things need to be adressed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the confusion which package to use, our code has the following problems:

- you haven't imported the classes you are using, and thus, PHP cannot find the classes within the root namespace
- you are passing in parameters to constructors and other methods that aren't used, or have the wrong type
- you apparently have undefined variables (for example, `$stomp` is undefined, or it's missing from the code example)

I suggest tackling these problems one by one.

### Using `fusesource/stomp-php`

#### Import the classes you are using

Adjust your list of imports (these are the `use` statements) to include the classes you are referencing in the code example:

```
use FuseSource\Stomp\Exception\StompException;
use FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp;
```

If there are more classes from the package that your code example omits, include them in your imports as well.

#### Remove unnecessary parameters

When you create an instance of `FuseSource\Stomp\Stomp`, you are passing in parameters the constructor doesn't use.

Change

```
$con = new Stomp($url, $user, $password);
```

to

```
$con = new Stomp($url);
```

#### Undefined variables

You have a line of code where you reference an undefined variable `$stomp`, where you probably intend to use `$con` instead.

Change

```
$stomp->send($destination, "SHUTDOWN");
```

to

```
$con->send($destination, new Message("SHUTDOWN"));
```

### Using `stomp-php/stomp-php`

#### Import the classes you are using

Adjust your list of imports (these are the `use` statements) to include the classes you are referencing in the code example:

```
use Stomp\Client;
use Stomp\Exception\StompException;
use Stomp\StatefulStomp;
use Stomp\Transport\Message;
```

If there are more classes from the package that your code example omits, include them in your imports as well.

#### Remove unnecessary parameters

The constructor of `Stomp\Stomp\StatefulStomp` has a different signature than that of `FuseSource\Stomp`.

Change

```
$con = new Stomp($url, $user, $password);
```

to

```
$con = new StatefulStomp(new Client($url));
```

#### Adjust parameters to the required type

The signature of `send()` has changed.

Change

```
$con->send($destination, $body);
```

to

```
$con->send($destination, new Message($body));
```

#### Undefined variables

You have a line of code where you reference an undefined variable `$stomp`, where you probably intend to use `$con` instead.

Change

```
$stomp->send($destination, "SHUTDOWN");
```

to

```
$con->send($destination, new Message("SHUTDOWN"));
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php
- https://github.com/dejanb/stomp-php
- https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php

Comment: Updated my answer to address the issues in your code example.

Comment: Since fusesource was deprecated, i unistalled and use this repository: https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php
So i no longer have Fusesource library but stomp... I installed it via composer...

Comment: Adjusted the answer to include corrections for both `fusesource/stomp-php` and `stomp-php/stomp-php`.

Comment: The part of the undefined variables it was an error, since, i replaced what i originally had 'stomp' to 'con' and forgot one line... Thank you.

Comment: Does this work for you now? If so, please accept my answer (take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).